# Why does VIM disregard my file's BOM?

Tags: vim, utf-8, byte-order-mark

I need a file that I want to make sure is encoded with *utf8*.

So, I create the file

```
c:\> gvim umlaute.txt
```

In VIM I type the Umlaute:

```
äöü
```

I check the encoding ...

```
:set enc
```

(VIM echoes `encoding=latin1`)

and then I check the file encoding ...

```
:set fenc
```

(VIM echoes `fileencoding=`)

Then I write the file

```
:w
```

And check the file's size on the harddisk:

```
!dir umlaute.txt
```

(The size is 5 bytes) That is of course expected, 3 bytes for the text and 2 for the \x0a \x0d.

Ok, so I now set the encoding to

```
:set enc=utf8
```

The buffer get's wierd

```
<e4><f6><fc>
```

I guess this is the hex representation of the ascii characters I previously typed in. So I *rewrite* them

```
äöü
```

Writing, checking size:

```
:w
:$ dir umlaute.txt
```

This time, it's 8 bytes. I guess that makes sense 2 bytes for every character plus \x0d \x0a.

Ok, so I want to make sure the next time I open the file it will be opened with encodiung=utf8.

```
:setb
:w

:$ dir umlaute.txt
```

11 Bytes. This is of course 8 (previous) Bytes + 3 Bytes for the BOM (ef bb bf).

So I

```
:quit
```

vim and open the file again

and check, if the encoding is set:

```
:set enc
```

But VIM insists its `encoding=latin1`.

So, why is that. I would have expected the BOM to tell VIM that this is a UTF8 file.

Comment: I add this string to my files `# vim: set fileencoding=utf-8` to make sure I get utf-8 in vim

Comment: The problem is: I have so many (old and legacy) files that I am not sure if I want to mess with them just for this particular one.

Comment: UTF-8 isn’t very BOM friendly. It is neither required **nor recommended** to put a BOM in a UTF-8 file.  Everything I know that reads UTF-8 streams will treat a BOM as an extra character at the start of the data, *not* as a BOM metadatum.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are confusing `'encoding'` which is a Vim global setting, and `'fileencoding'`, which is a local setting to each buffer.

When opening a file, the variable `'fileencodings'` (note the final *s*) determines what encodings Vim will try to open the file with. If it starts with `ucs-bom` then any file with a BOM will be properly opened if it parses correctly.

If you want to change the encoding of a file, you should use `:set fenc=<foo>`. If you want to remove the BOM you should use `:set [no]bomb`. Then use `:w` to save.

Avoid changing `enc` after having opened a buffer, it could mess up things. `enc` determines what characters vim can work with, and it has nothing to do with the files that you are working with.

### Details

> `c:\> gvim umlaute.txt`

You are opening vim, with a nonexistent file name. Vim creates a buffer, gives it that name, and sets `fenc` to an empty value since there is no file associated with it.

> `:set enc`
>
> (VIM echoes encoding=latin1)

This means that the Vim stores the buffer contents in ISO-8859-1 (maybe another number).

> and then I check the file encoding ...
>
> `:set fenc`
>
> (VIM echoes fileencoding=)

This is normal, there is no file for the moment.

> Then I write the file
>
> `:w`

Since `'fileencoding'` is empty, it will write it to the disk using the internal encoding, `latin1`.

> And check the file's size on the harddisk:
>
> `!dir umlaute.txt`
>
> (The size is 5 bytes) That is of course expected, 3 bytes for the text and 2 for the \x0a \x0d.
>
> Ok, so I now set the encoding to
>
> `:set enc=utf8`

**WRONG!** You are telling vim that it must interpret the buffer contents as UTF8 content. the buffer contains, in hexadecimal, `e4 f6 fc 0a 0d`, the first three bytes are invalid UTF8 character sequences. You **should** have typed `:set fenc=utf-8`. This would have converted the buffer.

> The buffer get's wierd

That's what happens when you force Vim to interpret an illegal UTF-8 file as UTF8.

> I guess this is the hex representation of the ascii characters I previously typed in. So I rewrite them
>
> äöü
>
> Writing, checking size:
>
> `:w`
> `:$ dir umlaute.txt`
>
> This time, it's 8 bytes. I guess that makes sense 2 bytes for every character plus \x0d \x0a.
>
> Ok, so I want to make sure the next time I open the file it will be opened with encodiung=utf8.
>
> `:set bomb`
> `:w`
>
> :$ dir umlaute.txt
>
> 11 Bytes. This is of course 8 (previous) Bytes + 3 Bytes for the BOM (ef bb bf).
>
> So I
>
> `:quit`
>
> vim and open the file again
>
> and check, if the encoding is set:
>
> :set enc
>
> But VIM insists its encoding=latin1.

You should run `set fenc?` to know what is the detected encoding of your file. And if you want Vim to be able to work with Unicode files, you should set in your vimrc that `'enc'` is utf-8.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanations. I appreciated them very much!

Comment: @René Nyfenegger: You are welcome. I have the feeling that I help you on Vim while you help me on SQL*Plus (I have browsed your web site a lot Yesterday).

Answer (score 3):

After many attempts I get here is a working example:

```
    setglobal bomb 
    set fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf-8,cp1251,koi8-r,cp866
    set nobin
    set fileencoding=utf-8 bomb
```

and if you want to cteate new fiel with BOM:

```
    c:\gvim umlaute.txt
```

it is working now!

Answer (score 1):

`:help bomb` reveals the following information:

> When writing a file and the following conditions are met, a BOM (Byte Order Mark) is prepended to the file:
>
> - this option is on (edit: i.e. ':set bomb')
> - the 'binary' option is off
> - 'fileencoding' is "utf-8", "ucs-2", "ucs-4" or one of the little/big endian variants.
>
> Some applications use the BOM to recognize the encoding of the file.
>   Often used for UCS-2 files on MS-Windows.  For other applications it
>   causes trouble, for example: "cat file1 file2" makes the BOM of file2
>   appear halfway the resulting file.  Gcc doesn't accept a BOM.
>   When Vim reads a file and 'fileencodings' starts with "ucs-bom", a
>   check for the presence of the BOM is done and 'bomb' set accordingly.
>   Unless 'binary' is set, it is removed from the first line, so that you
>   don't see it when editing.  When you don't change the options, the BOM
>   will be restored when writing the file.

So try setting this in your .vimrc:

```
set fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf-8,latin1
set nobin
setglobal fileencoding=utf-8
```